# IOS memory data not deleting after logout button

Tags: ios, xcode, memory

I am developing a social network, it almost finished but there is memory problem. In login page memory usage is 35 mb i want back this memory usage when I logouted.

When i pressed logout button i want decreasing of usage memory. for example while login, memory is 79,6 mb memory in `XCode` screen, but i apply below codes memory usage  75,5 mb.and when i relogin memory increases from 75 to 75+40(115mb). how can i deal with this?

the code that i used for logout:

```
-(void)logout{
    //these are deleting 4 mb from memory
    for(UIView *view in self.c_ProfilePage.view.subviews){
                   [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    for(UIView *view in self.c_MainPage.view.subviews){
                   [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    self.c_MainPage.checkinsArray = nil;
    self.c_MainPage.checkinsTable = nil;
    self.c_MainPage.Badge = nil;
    self.c_MainPage.button_checkinPage = nil;
    self.c_MainPage.button_profilePage = nil;
    self.c_MainPage.bufferData = nil;

    self.c_ProfilePage.checkinsArray = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.checkinsTable = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.m_SubView = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.AddFriendButton = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.refreshControl = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.navController = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.window = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.e_profilepicture = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.view_profilepicture = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.label_name = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.label_surname = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.label_username = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.label_tweetCount = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.label_friendCount = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.bufferFriendList = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage.rightPanel = nil;

    [self.c_publicFunctions logoutRequest];
    self.c_MainPage = nil;
    self.c_ProfilePage = nil;
    self.c_ChatMenu = nil;
    self.database_sql = nil;
    self.c_publicFunctions = nil;
    self.c_publicFunctions = [publicFunctions alloc];
    self.c_Map = nil;
    self.CUser = nil;
    _CUser = [[Account  alloc]init];
    self.window = nil;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.c_MainPageController = nil;
     self.c_MainPage =[[mainPage alloc]init];
    [self.c_MainPageController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    self.c_MainPageController = [[mainPageController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.c_MainPage];
    [self.c_MainPageController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self.memory_default removeObjectForKey:@"AutoLogin"];
    [self.memory_default removeObjectForKey:@"username"];
    [self.memory_default removeObjectForKey:@"password"];
    [self.memory_default setObject:@"0" forKey:@"AutoLogin"];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.c_LoginPage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some delegates in this controller set them to nil, and you need to dismis this controller or pop if is navigation controller, this can help.

Comment: I added these codes but still same it is around 72 mb
self.c_MainPage.checkinsTable.delegate = nil;
self.c_ProfilePage.checkinsTable.delegate = nil;
Also i tried to add dismiss code to check whether memory usage will decrease or not.it wont be decreased.decrease

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: control if dealoc method is called


  ``- (void)dealloc
  {
    NSLog(@"dealloc - %@",[self class]);
  }
  ``

Comment: i added to dealloc method appdelegate it is not running when i logout what should i do?but in some page it is running.

Comment: do you have some observers in this controller? if you have you need to remove them.

Comment: observers?i heard it first.

Comment: Can you provide the files of this class? I want to see... maybe I can find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that dealloc of all controllers is begin called.
And in case if you have used any singleton..make sure you are cleaning up it too when logout.
Also if you are using any image cache library just in case , clear its cache too.